# Can't run 'git' in git bash ... "bash: /mingw32/bin/git: Bad address"

Tags: windows, git, mingw

- Uninstalled git entirely
- Fresh install of git-2.11.0.windows.3 (including git bash)
- In freshly installed git bash (mingw32) I type 'git'. See error

  bash: /mingw32/bin/git: Bad address
- Typing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\bin\git.exe in Command Prompt works just fine

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this exact problem, in my case it was caused by the ORIGINAL_PATH variable in git bash. It doesn't like having entries containing `\\` or `//`.

To solve this:

1. Completely uninstall git
2. Go to System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
3. Delete any entries containing `\\` from Path for User variables and System variables
4. Install git again

Alternatively, you could edit ORIGINAL_PATH and PATH in Git Bash directly, to remove such entries.

Comment: Nice, but my system runs not only Git, but Cygwin and Emacs as well, and they rely on some network shares in their paths, like `//myserver/home/bin`. In fact both Emacs and Cygwin expect `$HOME` to be `//myserver/home`. Isn't there a way to fix **Git for Windows** to behave nicely with `//`?

Comment: That's currently being addressed by the Git for Windows development team, and I think a fix should be in the next release.

As a temporary measure, you could always modify the values of PATH and ORIGINAL_PATH in the Git Bash terminal manually each time you open it, or find a way to permanently change those values in the Git Bash terminal without modifying your Windows path.

Comment: I have also such issue in 2021 ))) But I have checked ORIGINAL_PATH and PATH and there is not // or \\ symbols